# Can I use cilantro instead of basil on a bruschetta?

Tags: bread

Ran out of basil at the last moment, can substitute the basil for cilantro? I know people will notice the difference but would still be acceptable?

Comment: VTC on opinion.  You can substitute anything you want. Basil and cilantro do not taste the same.  Cilantro for parsley yes.

Answer (score 7):

It will obviously not have the same flavour, but I imagine it will still taste good. It will not be a traditional Italian flavour, since cilantro is not native to Italy, but there's nothing inherently wrong with that. There is no chemical reaction that needs to happen with the basil in particular for a bruschetta so you can really top the bread with anything you like.